# Find decompression algorithm based on known compression implementation

Tags: decompress

I have been trying to figure out how this compression algorithm works, so I can write a decompression tool for it.

The compressed data consists of the following layout:

```
0x00 →  0x03 : uncompressed data size (4 bytes, e.g. 0x80)
0x04 →  0x83 : multibyte table (named `_ptrArray`)
0x84 → 0x103 : 0x80 first bytes of the uncompressed data
the rest is the actual compressed data that I'm trying to figure out
```

I'm having no luck understanding how the data is actually being compressed, and so far I'm unable to recover the original data from the compression output.

I'm not sure what I should do next, the attempts I made thus far have been failed.  I would deeply appreciate any help or advice I can get in order to understand this compression mechanism, and write a decompression tool for it.

Here's the reference implementation to **compress** the data, and the sample I've been working on:

#### Uncompressed data

https://pastebin.com/6sQyFY30

#### Compressed data

```
80 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08 00 09 00 0A 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 12 00 13 00 14 00 15 00 16 00 17 00 18 00 19 00 1A 00 1B 00 1C 00 1D 00 1E 00 1F 00 20 00 21 00 22 00 23 00 24 00 25 00 26 00 27 00 28 00 29 00 2A 00 2B 00 2C 00 75 00 76 00 77 00 78 00 79 00 7A 00 7B 00 7C 00 7D 00 7E 00 7F 00 80 00 81 00 82 00 83 00 84 00 85 00 86 00 87 00 88 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 93 37 A1 2B 8E 00 C0 37 00 0F 84 37 01 E0 FE AE 35 01 FE E0 84 36 00 0F B8 37 03 FF 7F 0F 03 83 39 05 80 E0 F0 F8 FC FE A1 3E 06 FE FE FC F8 F0 E0 80 83 34 02 03 0F 7F B9 36 82 00 06 3F 1F 0F 07 03 01 01 83 3F 02 00 00 80 80 00 00 C0 91 00 81 18 85 24 06 01 01 03 07 0F 1F 3F BE 33 8A 00 04 7F 7F 3F 3F 1F 80 00 00 0F 83 00 00 07 87 00 84 11 81 1C 04 3F 3F 7F 7F 7F CB 2F F7 00 00 E0 C1 00 B8 37 00 00 84 00 00 07 94 00 9D 1F 82 00 C0 37 B5 1F BD 00 00 03 84 37 01 F0 FE 92 1E 00 F0 85 37 02 C0 F8 FC 93 21 BD 00 02 3F 07 01 83 39 06 80 C0 E0 F0 F0 F0 F8 85 00 04 F0 F0 E0 C0 80 81 17 03 01 07 7F 0F 84 23 00 80 80 23 80 24 05 F8 F8 FC FC FE FE C9 3B 06 1F 0F 0F 07 03 03 01 81 00 00 00 82 00 81 09 06 03 03 07 0F 1F 3F 7F 84 23 03 7F 7F 3F 1F 81 26 00 07 80 26 83 23 09 00 80 80 C0 C0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F8 C5 3F A7 00 0D 7F 7F 3F 3F 1F 1F 0F 07 07 03 03 01 01 00 C3 2C 00 FE 81 00 00 FC 82 00 81 09 9B 38 81 21 83 00 BD 2E 07 FC F8 F0 E0 C0 80 80 00 8F 00 04 80 C0 E0 F0 F8 95 3F 02 3F 0F 01 84 25 00 F0 B8 3A 01 F0 C0 83 2C 06 01 07 1F 3F 3F 7F 7F 85 16 04 7F 7F 3F 0F 07 85 3D 01 E0 FC 95 3A 00 03 84 22 00 F8 B5 36 83 34 02 00 00 3F 92 1D 00 1F 85 1E 00 C0 95 39 85 20 B5 37 00 0F 84 37 00 F0 95 1F 00 01 85 39 01 F8 FE 8E 1C 02 FC F0 80 83 1C 01 01 1F B5 37 03 FF 7F 0F 01 83 39 02 C0 F0 FC 92 20 02 3F 0F 07 85 3B 03 80 C0 C0 E0 85 00 01 C0 80 85 33 02 03 0F 3F B6 35 83 3A 86 00 98 22 03 3F 1F 1F 0F 81 00 00 07 83 00 81 0A 04 1F 1F 3F 3F 7F BB 32 FF C0 FE C0 00 FC C1 00 B8 37 00 00 C1 00 C0 37 A1 2B 8E 00 C0 37 00 0F 84 37 01 E0 FE AE 35 01 FE E0 84 36 00 0F B8 37 03 FF 7F 0F 03 83 39 05 80 E0 F0 F8 FC FE A1 3E 06 FE FE FC F8 F0 E0 80 83 34 02 03 0F 7F B9 36 82 00 06 3F 1F 0F 07 03 01 01 83 3F 02 00 00 80 80 00 00 C0 91 00 81 18 85 24 06 01 01 03 07 0F 1F 3F BE 33 8A 00 04 7F 7F 3F 3F 1F 80 00 00 0F 83 00 00 07 87 00 84 11 81 1C 04 3F 3F 7F 7F 7F CB 2F 8B 40 00 FE 84 00 8C 15 04 FC F8 F8 F0 E0 80 00 00 C0 82 00 80 08 04 F0 F0 F8 F8 FC 8C 25 BE 00 02 FC E0 00 81 00 02 01 0F 3F 89 33 01 F0 C0 83 15 03 07 07 0F 1F 84 00 03 0F 07 03 01 82 14 01 C0 F0 C8 36 83 35 01 00 0F 91 14 01 07 7F 8B 2B 02 FF FF 3F 83 18 00 00 C7 37 00 01 83 37 00 FC 8A 14 83 13 00 00 8D 2B 02 FF FC E0 82 17 01 03 1F C7 37 02 FF 1F 03 82 3A 06 C0 E0 F0 F8 FC FC FE 83 00 84 37 84 0D 11 FE FC FC F8 F8 F0 F0 E0 C0 00 00 02 02 06 0E 3E 7E FE C8 36 81 00 08 7F 3F 1F 0F 07 07 03 03 01 82 00 84 34 99 00 CC 37 FB 00 05 F8 FC FC FE FE FE F7 37 03 01 01 01 00 82 00 11 80 80 C0 C0 C0 E0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F8 F8 F8 FC FC FC FE FE E8 3D 13 7F 7F 3F 3F 3F 1F 1F 1F 0F 0F 0F 07 07 03 03 03 01 01 01 00 81 00 12 80 80 80 C0 C0 E0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F0 F8 F8 FC FC FC FE FE FE DA 3F 8B 00 0E 7F 7F 3F 3F 3F 1F 1F 1F 0F 0F 0F 06 06 02 00 85 00 DB 2C 12 FE FE FE FC FC F8 F8 F8 F0 F0 F0 E0 E0 E0 C0 C0 80 80 80 82 2D 09 01 01 01 03 03 07 07 07 0F 0F CA 2C 0E FC F8 F8 F0 F0 F0 E0 E0 E0 C0 C0 80 80 80 00 82 00 11 01 01 03 03 03 07 07 07 0F 0F 1F 1F 1F 3F 3F 3F 7F 7F 83 2B D1 00 10 01 03 03 03 07 07 0F 0F 0F 1F 1F 1F 3F 3F 7F 7F 7F 98 2B FD 40 00 F0 83 00 CA 2C 00 80 83 00 A2 2B 00 00 83 00 B6 2C 00 FC 87 00 86 13 00 00 83 00 88 1A 97 00 BD 37 00 01 87 00 91 13 9E 00 BD 37 BD 00 FD 77 00 7F 83 00 D9 2C 00 FE 82 00 00 FC 84 00 83 0D 95 2B C4 00 0A FE FC F8 F0 E0 E0 C0 80 80 80 00 96 00 09 80 80 C0 C0 E0 E0 F0 F8 FC FE CC 34 01 F0 C0 82 2C 0A 01 03 07 0F 1F 1F 3F 3F 7F 7F 7F 8D 21 80 12 07 3F 3F 3F 1F 0F 07 03 01 82 2A 01 C0 F0 C8 36 82 34 02 00 00 3F A1 2B 02 FF FF 3F 82 38 01 00 00 C7 37 02 3F 07 01 81 37 03 C0 F8 FC FE 9D 2A 03 FE FC F8 C0 81 2B 02 01 07 3F B5 2C 00 F0 91 00 02 70 30 10 81 3A 08 00 00 80 C0 C0 C0 E0 E0 E0 8D 1F 80 12 80 18 00 80 83 23 04 10 30 70 F0 F0 B5 36 01 FF 07 C3 00 B6 37 FF C0 FF C0 86 00 00 FE 81 00 00 FC 82 00 81 09 9B 2C 81 21 83 00 BD 2E 07 FC F8 F0 E0 C0 80 80 00 8F 00 04 80 C0 E0 F0 F8 95 3F 02 3F 0F 01 84 25 00 F0 B8 3A 01 F0 C0 83 2C 06 01 07 1F 3F 3F 7F 7F 85 16 04 7F 7F 3F 0F 07 85 3D 01 E0 FC 95 3A 00 03 84 22 00 F8 B5 36 83 34 02 00 00 3F 92 1D 00 1F 85 1E 00 C0 95 39 85 20 B5 37 00 0F 84 37 00 F0 95 1F 00 01 85 39 01 F8 FE 8E 1C 02 FC F0 80 83 1C 01 01 1F B5 37 03 FF 7F 0F 01 83 39 02 C0 F0 FC 92 20 02 3F 0F 07 85 3B 03 80 C0 C0 E0 85 00 01 C0 80 85 33 02 03 0F 3F B6 35 83 3A 86 00 98 22 03 3F 1F 1F 0F 81 00 00 07 83 00 81 0A 04 1F 1F 3F 3F 7F BB 32 98 40 08 FE FC FC F8 F8 F0 F0 F0 E0 83 00 00 C0 84 00 84 0E 80 18 04 F8 F8 FC FC FE D1 31 05 FC F0 E0 C0 80 00 81 00 07 01 03 03 03 07 07 07 0F 8C 00 80 12 80 18 00 01 82 22 04 80 C0 E0 F0 FC C9 35 00 F0 82 31 04 00 03 1F 3F 7F 9D 2A 03 7F 3F 1F 03 82 3C 01 00 F0 C7 37 00 01 83 37 00 F8 A1 2B 02 FF FF F8 83 37 00 01 C7 37 02 FF 1F 07 83 3A 06 80 C0 E0 F0 F8 F8 FC 80 00 00 FE 8C 00 81 13 05 F8 F8 F0 E0 E0 80 83 34 01 07 1F C8 36 82 00 0B 7F 3F 1F 0F 07 07 03 03 01 01 01 00 92 00 80 18 07 03 03 07 07 0F 1F 3F 7F CD 33 92 00 00 7F 86 00 9F 2B BD 40 00 C0 83 00 F6 37 00 00 83 00 E4 2C 06 FC F8 F0 E0 C0 C0 80 81 00 84 30 B0 00 B6 35 01 E0 00 82 00 04 07 1F 3F 3F 7F 85 00 84 2C 86 0F A0 00 B6 37 83 36 00 00 9E 13 D5 00 00 0F 83 00 9E 13 E9 40 00 C0 83 00 F6 37 00 00 83 00 E7 2C 00 80 8B 00 84 37 8C 15 8F 00 08 C0 C0 C0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F8 FE BD 37 00 3F 8B 00 84 37 8C 15 8F 00 03 1F 1F 07 01 82 29 01 80 F8 BD 39 8A 00 84 37 CE 2B A5 00 00 03 83 00 CE 2B FF C0 FF C0 A3 40 00 FE 84 00 8C 15 04 FC F8 F8 F0 E0 80 00 00 C0 82 00 80 08 04 F0 F0 F8 F8 FC 8C 25 BE 00 02 FC E0 00 81 00 02 01 0F 3F 89 33 01 F0 C0 83 15 03 07 07 0F 1F 84 00 03 0F 07 03 01 82 14 01 C0 F0 C8 36 83 35 01 00 0F 91 14 01 07 7F 8B 2B 02 FF FF 3F 83 18 00 00 C7 37 00 01 83 37 00 FC 8A 14 83 13 00 00 8D 2B 02 FF FC E0 82 17 01 03 1F C7 37 02 FF 1F 03 82 3A 06 C0 E0 F0 F8 FC FC FE 83 00 84 37 84 0D 11 FE FC FC F8 F8 F0 F0 E0 C0 00 00 02 02 06 0E 3E 7E FE C8 36 81 00 08 7F 3F 1F 0F 07 07 03 03 01 82 00 84 34 99 00 CC 37 FB 00 00 FC 83 00 F6 37 00 00 83 00 E7 2C 00 F8 8B 00 84 37 8C 15 8F 00 04 FC FC FC FE FE C1 37 00 03 8B 00 84 37 8C 15 8F 00 01 01 01 82 27 02 80 E0 F8 C1 3C 87 00 84 37 A0 29 01 7F 1F 83 2A 00 80 F4 37 AB 2B A5 00 00 3F 83 00 CE 2B FF C0 FF C0 C3 00 09 FE FE FE FC FC FC F8 F8 F8 F0 80 00 03 E0 E0 E0 C0 D3 2C 09 FE FE FE FC FC FC F8 F8 F8 F0 80 00 09 E0 E0 E0 C0 C0 C0 80 80 80 00 85 00 00 01 80 00 06 03 03 03 07 07 07 0F BA 2C 09 FE FE FE FC FC FC F8 F8 F8 F0 80 00 09 E0 E0 E0 C0 C0 C0 80 80 80 00 83 00 00 01 80 00 03 03 03 03 07 80 00 01 0F 0F 85 31 03 7F 7F 7F FF C5 00 00 00 86 00 07 06 06 06 07 0F 0F 0F 1F 80 00 03 3F 3F 3F 7F 80 00 95 2B C6 34 80 00 0A 0F 0F 07 07 07 03 03 03 01 01 01 83 3E 03 80 80 80 C0 80 00 03 E0 E0 E0 F0 80 00 03 F8 F8 F8 FC 80 00 02 FE FE FE D4 37 8B 00 06 7F 7F 7F 3F 3F 3F 1F 80 00 0B 0F 0F 0F 07 07 07 03 03 03 01 01 01 85 2F 85 00 0C E0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F0 F8 F8 F8 FC FC FC FE 80 00 CF 3F 8E 00 06 7F 7F 7F 3F 3F 3F 1F 80 00 0C 0F 0F 0F 07 07 07 03 03 03 01 01 01 00 84 00 E0 38 95 00 04 7F 7F 7F 3F 3F BD 2C 06 FE FC F8 F8 F0 F0 E0 81 00 00 C0 82 00 81 09 04 F0 F0 F8 FC FE 96 2F 01 EF E3 81 23 81 00 00 F8 BA 32 04 FC F0 C0 80 00 81 00 05 01 03 03 07 07 0F 84 00 02 07 07 03 82 14 04 00 00 80 E0 F8 95 3C 00 1F 85 23 00 E0 B6 35 00 F0 82 32 04 00 00 03 1F 7F 8E 1B 02 7F 0F 01 84 1D 01 C0 FC 94 39 00 3F 84 20 00 80 B5 37 84 36 00 00 94 1E 00 0F 85 1F 94 39 00 F8 84 1E 00 01 B5 37 01 FF 07 84 38 01 F0 FC 93 1F 01 1F 03 84 20 06 80 E0 F0 F8 FC FC FE 85 00 04 FC F8 F8 F0 C0 84 1A 01 03 1F B6 36 80 00 01 1F 07 84 00 01 C7 F7 93 20 07 7F 1F 0F 07 07 03 01 01 83 3F 87 00 07 01 01 03 03 07 0F 1F 3F B9 34 AE 00 00 7F 83 00 A2 2B D6 00 09 FE FE FE FC FC FC F8 F8 F8 F0 80 00 03 E0 E0 E0 C0 D3 2C 09 FE FE FE FC FC FC F8 F8 F8 F0 80 00 09 E0 E0 E0 C0 C0 C0 80 80 80 00 85 00 00 01 80 00 06 03 03 03 07 07 07 0F BA 2C 09 FE FE FE FC FC FC F8 F8 F8 F0 80 00 09 E0 E0 E0 C0 C0 C0 80 80 80 00 83 00 00 01 80 00 03 03 03 03 07 80 00 01 0F 0F 85 31 03 7F 7F 7F FF C5 00 00 00 86 00 07 06 06 06 07 0F 0F 0F 1F 80 00 03 3F 3F 3F 7F 80 00 95 2B C6 34 80 00 0A 0F 0F 07 07 07 03 03 03 01 01 01 83 3E 03 80 80 80 C0 80 00 03 E0 E0 E0 F0 80 00 03 F8 F8 F8 FC 80 00 02 FE FE FE D4 37 8B 00 06 7F 7F 7F 3F 3F 3F 1F 80 00 0B 0F 0F 0F 07 07 07 03 03 03 01 01 01 85 2F 85 00 0C E0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F0 F8 F8 F8 FC FC FC FE 80 00 CF 3F 8E 00 06 7F 7F 7F 3F 3F 3F 1F 80 00 0C 0F 0F 0F 07 07 07 03 03 03 01 01 01 00 84 00 E0 38 95 00 04 7F 7F 7F 3F 3F F8 37 FF C0 D1 80 00 FE 83 00 00 FC 86 00 84 10 D5 2C 0C FE FC F8 F8 F0 E0 E0 C0 C0 80 80 80 00 9C 00 80 22 08 C0 C0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F8 FC FE C0 31 04 F8 F0 C0 80 00 82 00 09 01 03 07 07 0F 0F 1F 1F 1F 3F 81 00 00 7F 8E 00 82 16 80 1E 06 0F 0F 07 07 03 01 00 82 00 03 80 C0 E0 F8 B8 3D 01 FC C0 84 32 02 0F 3F 7F 9D 2B 8D 00 02 7F 3F 0F 84 3C 01 C0 FC B5 37 83 35 01 00 00 AD 33 85 00 83 37 01 00 00 B5 37 02 7F 07 01 83 38 02 E0 F8 FE AD 33 02 FE FC E0 83 34 02 01 07 7F B5 37 81 3A 01 1F 0F 83 00 02 8F CF EF A7 34 03 EF CF 8F 0F 83 00 00 1F B9 34 97 40 08 FE FC FC F8 F8 F0 F0 F0 E0 83 00 00 C0 84 00 84 0E 80 18 04 F8 F8 FC FC FE D1 31 05 FC F0 E0 C0 80 00 81 00 07 01 03 03 03 07 07 07 0F 8C 00 80 12 80 18 00 01 82 22 04 80 C0 E0 F0 FC C9 35 00 F0 82 31 04 00 03 1F 3F 7F 9D 2A 03 7F 3F 1F 03 82 3C 01 00 F0 C7 37 00 01 83 37 00 F8 A1 2B 02 FF FF F8 83 37 00 01 C7 37 02 FF 1F 07 83 3A 06 80 C0 E0 F0 F8 F8 FC 80 00 00 FE 8C 00 81 13 05 F8 F8 F0 E0 E0 80 83 34 01 07 1F C8 36 82 00 0B 7F 3F 1F 0F 07 07 03 03 01 01 01 00 92 00 80 18 07 03 03 07 07 0F 1F 3F 7F CD 33 92 00 00 7F 86 00 9F 2B BD 00 00 F8 AF 00 CA 37 03 03 02 02 00 80 00 03 01 01 01 03 A5 00 C8 35 01 F0 C0 81 34 01 00 3E A1 2B D1 00 02 1F 07 01 82 38 03 00 80 80 C0 A6 00 C9 38 0B FC F0 E0 E0 40 00 01 07 0F 0F 0F 1F A5 00 C8 36 00 00 83 00 04 F0 F8 FC FC FE A6 00 C8 37 08 FF 3F 1F 0F 07 03 03 03 01 82 00 00 00 A3 00 C9 37 FE 00 00 FC C3 00 B6 37 00 03 80 00 01 02 00 85 00 00 01 80 00 81 11 87 00 81 11 86 1E 01 02 02 8B 1C 87 00 B5 36 03 F8 E0 C0 80 80 2F 05 03 0F 1F 3F 7F 7F 97 26 05 7F 7F 3F 1F 0F 03 81 3A 02 C0 E0 F8 97 26 AE 00 81 33 80 00 A2 2B 80 00 81 2B 80 00 C7 37 01 1F 03 83 38 04 E0 F0 FC FC FE 99 28 04 FE FC FC F0 E0 83 2B 01 03 1F C7 37 80 00 05 3F 1F 0F 07 03 01 83 3E 03 80 80 80 C0 8E 00 80 14 83 1D 05 01 03 07 0F 1F 3F CA 34 88 00 05 7F 7F 3F 3F 3F 1F 81 00 00 0F 88 00 82 10 80 18 01 7F 7F D5 2F 99 00 00 FE 80 00 00 FC 82 00 80 08 D3 2C 02 FE F0 E0 82 00 01 E3 EF 89 15 06 FC F0 E0 C0 80 80 00 80 00 00 01 84 00 81 0B 05 80 80 C0 E0 F0 FC CA 35 01 C0 00 82 00 00 1F 8A 14 00 E0 83 14 03 07 1F 7F 7F 87 15 03 7F 3F 1F 03 83 17 00 F0 C7 37 83 35 00 00 92 14 88 33 84 00 00 FE 83 18 00 01 C7 37 01 1F 01 82 37 02 C0 FC FE 8F 37 8C 33 02 FC F0 C0 81 15 02 03 07 3F C7 36 80 00 03 3F 1F 07 03 82 3C 03 80 C0 C0 E0 83 00 84 37 84 0D 04 E0 C0 C0 80 80 83 11 02 20 20 60 81 10 CA 37 83 00 04 7F 7F 3F 3F 1F 82 00 00 0F 9F 00 D0 37 F7 00 00 FC AF 00 CA 37 00 03 80 00 02 02 02 00 82 00 00 01 80 00 81 0F 9C 00 C9 36 03 FC F0 C0 80 80 30 04 07 1F 3F 7F 7F 9D 2B D0 00 80 33 81 00 00 FE F0 32 82 00 01 1F 03 83 38 06 80 E0 F0 F0 F8 F8 FC A3 00 CB 3A 08 7F 3F 1F 1F 0F 0F 07 07 03 82 00 00 01 A0 00 CB 37 FC 00 04 F8 FC FC FE FE F8 37 01 01 00 83 00 10 80 80 C0 C0 C0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F8 F8 F8 FC FC FE FE FE A4 2C 00 80 83 00 BA 3B 11 7F 7F 3F 3F 3F 1F 1F 0F 0F 0F 07 07 03 03 03 01 01 00 82 00 10 80 80 C0 C0 C0 E0 E0 F0 F0 F0 F8 F8 FC FC FE FE FE 8B 31 05 FE FC FC F8 F0 C0 83 2A 00 07 BA 37 91 00 0F 7F 7F 3F 3F 3F 1F 1F 0F 0F 0F 07 07 03 03 02 00 83 00 03 80 80 80 C0 80 00 01 80 80 82 0D 08 01 01 01 03 07 07 0F 1F 7F CA 31 11 FE FE FE FC FC F8 F8 F8 F0 F0 E0 E0 E0 C0 C0 80 80 80 82 32 0F 01 01 03 03 03 07 07 0F 0F 0F 1F 1F 3F 3F 3F 7F C4 2C 0F FC FC FC F8 F8 F0 F0 F0 E0 E0 C0 C0 C0 80 80 00 82 00 10 01 01 03 03 03 07 07 0F 0F 0F 1F 1F 3F 3F 3F 7F 7F 83 2B D1 00 11 00 01 01 01 03 03 07 07 07 0F 0F 1F 1F 3F 3F 3F 7F 7F 97 2B FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 FF C0 DF 80
```

#### Compression routine (code below)

```
const COMPRESS_SAMPLE_RATE =   0x800,
      TABLE_PTR_SIZE =         0x40,
      MAX_UNCOMPRESSED_BYTES = 0x80,
      MAX_COMPRESSED_BYTES =   0x202,
      MIN_COMPRESSED_BYTES =   0x2,

      COMPRESSION_FLAG =       0x80;

_ptrArray = [];

function lookupBestOccurs(data, size)
{
    // var occurs[COMPRESS_SAMPLE_RATE][2];
    var occurs = Array(COMPRESS_SAMPLE_RATE).fill(0).map(x => Array(2).fill(0));

    var oneIsPresent = false;
    var b;
    var i;

    // Initialize the table
    // occurs[i][0] = number of occurrences of the offset
    // occurs[i][1] = offset
    for (i=0; i < COMPRESS_SAMPLE_RATE; i++) {
        occurs[i][0] = 0;
        occurs[i][1] = i;
    }

    // Calculate the byte occurrence
    for (i=COMPRESS_SAMPLE_RATE; i < size; i += COMPRESS_SAMPLE_RATE) {
        b = data[i];
        for (let j=1; j < COMPRESS_SAMPLE_RATE; j++)
            if (data[i - j] == b)
                occurs[(j - 1)][0]++;
    }

    // Order the array
    // qsort(occurs, COMPRESS_SAMPLE_RATE, sizeof(uint32_t)*2, __compare);
    occurs.sort( function(n1, n2) { return n2[0] - n1[0]; } );

    // Set the pointer table to use for compression
    for (i=0; i < TABLE_PTR_SIZE; i++) {
        _ptrArray[i] = occurs[i][1] + 1;
        if (_ptrArray[i] == 1)
            oneIsPresent = true;
    }
    // Append the value 1 which improves the compression of multiple same bytes
    if (!oneIsPresent)
        _ptrArray[TABLE_PTR_SIZE-1] = 1;

    return true;
}

function compress(data, size)
{

    /* unsigned long */
    var r, w=4, uncompSize=0, maxCompSize, bestCompCounter, bestPtr;
    var rawDataCounter = 0, rawDataCounterPtr=0, maxOutputSize;

    var out = []; /* size: maxOutputSize */

    // Create the output buffer
    maxOutputSize = size;

    // Print the table
    for (let i = 0; i < TABLE_PTR_SIZE; i++, w += 2) {
        out[w] = _ptrArray[i];
        out[w+1] = _ptrArray[i] >> 8;
        if (_ptrArray[i] > uncompSize)
            uncompSize = _ptrArray[i];
    }

    // Print the first uncompressed bytes
    if (uncompSize > MAX_UNCOMPRESSED_BYTES)
        uncompSize = MAX_UNCOMPRESSED_BYTES;

    out[0] = uncompSize;
    out[1] = uncompSize>>8;
    out[2] = uncompSize>>16;
    out[3] = uncompSize>>24;

    for (r=0; r < uncompSize; r++, w++)
        out[w] = data[r];

    //
    // Compress the data
    //
    do {
        maxCompSize = size - r > MAX_COMPRESSED_BYTES ? MAX_COMPRESSED_BYTES :
            size - r;

        // End of the compression
        if (!maxCompSize) {
            if (rawDataCounter)
                out[rawDataCounterPtr] = rawDataCounter - 1;
            break;

        // Try to compress the next piece of data
        } else if (maxCompSize >= 2) {
            bestCompCounter = 0;
            bestPtr = 0;

            // Check if there is enough space
            if (w + 2 >= maxOutputSize) {
                w += 2;
                break;
            }

            // Check the best similar piece of data
            for (let i = 0; i < TABLE_PTR_SIZE; i++) {
                let counter;

                if (_ptrArray[i] > r)
                    continue;

                for (counter = 0; counter < maxCompSize; counter++)
                    if (data[r + counter] != data[r + counter - _ptrArray[i]])
                        break;

                if (counter > bestCompCounter) {
                    bestCompCounter = counter;
                    bestPtr = i;
                }
            }

            // If the reproduced piece is large enough, use it!
            if (bestCompCounter > MIN_COMPRESSED_BYTES) {
                r += bestCompCounter;
                bestCompCounter -= 3;
                
                out[w] = COMPRESSION_FLAG | (bestCompCounter & 0x7F);
                out[w+1] = ((bestCompCounter >> 1) & 0xC0) | (bestPtr & 0x3F);

                // _bestCompCounter = (out[w] & ~COMPRESSION_FLAG) + ((out[w+1] & 0xC0) << 1);
                // _bestPtr = out[w+1] & 0x3F;

                w += 2;
                if (rawDataCounter) {
                    out[rawDataCounterPtr] = rawDataCounter - 1;
                    rawDataCounter = 0;
                }
                continue;
            }
        }

        // Else write the uncompressed data
        rawDataCounter++;
        if (rawDataCounter == 1) {
            // Check if there is enough space
            if (w + 2 >= maxOutputSize) {
                w += 2;
                break;
            }
            rawDataCounterPtr = w;
            w++;
        } else if (rawDataCounter == MAX_UNCOMPRESSED_BYTES) {
            out[rawDataCounterPtr] = 0x7F;
            rawDataCounter = 0;
        }
        out[w] = data[r];
        w++;
        r++;
    } while (w < maxOutputSize);

    // Does the compression finished without any error?
    if (w >= maxOutputSize) {
        alert("No more space available in the output buffer for compression");
        return false;
    }

    // Copy the buffer in a best buffer
    outputSize = w;

    return out;
}

function initApp(t) {
    hexData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        hexData.push( t.charCodeAt(i) );

    const result = lookupBestOccurs(hexData, hexData.length) ?
                           compress(hexData, hexData.length) : [];

    return result;
}
```

Using the provided uncompressed data, compressed data, and the compression algorithm, how can I write a decompression mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

The question is a bit odd. If you have the code that generates the compressed data, you simply read it, understand it, then write a decompressor because you know how the compressed data was produced.

In your case it seems like Google Fu is easier.

I googled for `javascript "MAX_UNCOMPRESSED_BYTES"`, which led me to a file diff for a Gentoo package (called net-print splix or something I don't know what it is) that looked promising.

So I checked the source code and it seems like I found the original C++ source for your code, which was apparently transliterated to JavaScript from that (even the comments match):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/splix/

The C++ code for what you posted can be found in `splix-2.0.0\src\algo0x11.cpp`. There is also a decompressor in a different file `splix-2.0.0\tools\algo0x11.cpp`